# Rendering the Devise edit Password Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to render the Devise edit password form within another view because I don't want to duplicate the edit pw logic.

I've tried the following (after generating the Devise views):

```
<%= render 'devise/passwords/edit' %>
<%= render 'devise/passwords/form' %>
```

And a number of other variations on render that all seem to give me the same error:

"ActionView::MissingTemplate in foo#foo
Missing partial devise/passwords/edit..."

This variation:

```
  <%= render :file => 'devise/passwords/edit.html.erb' %>
```

Gave me some hope but the following error:

"undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x47ef0e0>"

around this line:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

That makes me think I'm close (as that is code from the form that I want) but shouldn't that template be using the correct logic from the hidden Devise controller?  Or do I need to do something in the routes file to get this to work?

Am I way off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= render :template => 'devise/passwords/edit', 
                        :locals => { 
                          :resource => my_user_model_variable, 
                          :resource_name => my_user_model_name } %>
```

Where:

- `my_user_model_variable` could be `current_user`
- `my_user_model_name` could be `"User"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Using "user" instead of "User" got me to a new error message:  undefined method `devise_error_messages!' for #<#<Class:0x4b92208>:0x4b44fd0>

Comment: Include the `devise_helper.rb` file to fix that (new) problem; or remove that call and use your own error reporting. And since my answer fixed your problem, you can accept it!

Comment: Thank you that worked.  One final question.  When the form is submitted with errors it redirects to the "/users" instead of the place I've rendered the form.  And on acceptance of a password change it redirects to the index page of the app.  How would I control these redirects?