# Rails 3 Devise manually change password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise, edit

I try to usung devise in my rails app. But i don't understand how can i give user functionality to change his password. I need a form with fields "old password", "new password" and "new password confirmation". How can i do it?

If i use default devise form on "/profile" page

```
<%= render :template => 'devise/passwords/edit', 
                        :locals => { 
                          :resource => my_user_model_variable, 
                          :resource_name => my_user_model_name } %>
```

In user.rb contain line

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
```

But there was 
`undefined method 'devise_error_messages!' for #<#<Class:0x59b9200>` and then (after commenting devise_error_messages! line)
`undefined method 'password' for #<Class:0x59b9200>` errors.

I try to use my own PasswordsController:

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    raise params.inspect
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Password updated!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

and use advise from this question: [Rendering the Devise edit Password Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915810/rendering-the-devise-edit-password-form)

insert this code

```
<%= render :template => 'passwords/edit', 
                    :locals => { 
                      :resource => current_user, 
                      :resource_name => User } %>
```

into "/profile" page.

passwords/edit.html.erb contain this code

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>
<%# raise resource.inspect %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%# devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <p><%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
  <%= password_field_tag :name => "user[password]"%></p>
  <%= password_field_tag :name => "user[password_confirmation]"%></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Change my password" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

But rendered form has "/profile" value for action attribute and submiting this form do nothing.

Comment: You should accept one of these answers if its right.

Answer (score 11):

Your form should be i.e. **password/edit.html.erb**

```
<%# raise resource.inspect %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%# devise_error_messages! %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

   <p><%= f.label :current_password %><br />
   <%= f.password_field :current_password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Change my password" %></p>
<% end %>
```

**VIEW**:

```
<h3>Change password </h3>
<hr/>
<%= render :template => 'passwords/edit', 
                    :locals => { :resource => current_user, :resource_name => "user" } %>
```

**Controller**:

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    # raise params.inspect
    if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Your Password has been updated!"
    else
      render :edit,:locals => { :resource => @user, :resource_name => "user" }
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes**:

```
devise_for :users ,:controllers => {:passwords => "passwords"} do
  end

  resources :passwords
```

It works for me;

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add quotes around User, as such:

```
<%= render :template => 'passwords/edit', 
                    :locals => { 
                      :resource => current_user, 
                      :resource_name => "User" } %>
```

Comment: I think the problem is in accessing "resource" from a different controller than a Devise controller. Try making your PasswordsController inherit from the Devise PasswordsController.