# devise password reset view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise, view

I'm trying to style my devise forms. So far I have done so by adding classes and IDs into the forms found in app/views/devise. However, I haven't been able to find where the form for /users/password/new (new_password_path) exists. It renders a button with "send me reset password instructions" on it; I did a search through my app and can't find where that comes from... Would that be in the Devise gem itself?

TL/DR: How can I style the forgot password view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607834/rails-3-devise-manually-change-password` refer this

Comment: My view at users/password/new looks like the below. What I'm wondering is where this is being generated from. It seems pretty standard, and was autogenerated for me; I just don't know how to edit it.                                                          `%h2 Forgot your password?
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { :method => :post }) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  %div
    = f.label :email
    %br/
    = f.email_field :email
  %div= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions"`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the Registrations and Sessions behaviour Devise provides a default Passwords view and controller that isn't automatically generated in your own application folder structure.

To override the Forgotten Password view create `new.html.erb` in a views/devise/passwords folder. You can see the default views on Devise's GitHub: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/views/devise/passwords

To override the PasswordsController create `passwords_controller.rb` in your app/controllers folder that inherits from the Devise controller and override whatever you need. For example to supply a non-default layout.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
    include ApplicationHelper
    layout "minimal"
end
```

You then need to change your routes.rb file to specify the custom controller should be used by devise:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions", :passwords => "passwords"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you **development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { 
:address => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
:port => your_port_num, 
:domain => 'site.com',
:user_name => 'admin@site.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:password => 'none' }
```

Your path with be redirected in mail.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I haven't configured my mailer yet; I'm just wondering how to style the page users/password/new, which is where a user inputs his/her email to be sent to the mailer. See my comment above... I can access that page in the browser, but I have no idea where it is coming from as I cannot find it in my app...