# Devise: Routes & after_sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I'm overriding the default Devise signin method as such:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)     
 stored_location_for(resource) || jobs_path
end
```

So that when an authenticated users signs in, they are taken to my jobs page.  Which is fine,
 but the problem I'm having is that I'd like to be able to utilize the Devise password (new/edit) pages, typically found at /users/password/new and /users/password/edit but when I attempt to go to those locations (http://localhost:3000/users/password/new), I get immediately redirected back to jobs page.  What do I need to do to correct this.  Below is part of my routes.rb if that helps:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions] do
  # devise/sessions
   get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
   post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
   get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :users
```

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The devise wiki says that users can edit their password using the registerable module:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Have you tried just using devises methods for letting users change their password?

Also, here is a related question:

[Rendering the Devise edit Password Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915810/rendering-the-devise-edit-password-form)